# WP REST API not retrieving all categories

Tags: categories, taxonomy, rest-api

I am developing a project that is using the WP REST API. After some tests, I realized that it's not retrieving all the categories based on what I am trying to GET. In precise, there are supposed to be 21 results but only 10 come up. Is there some kind of restriction that I am not seeing? Any settings that I'll have to change.

Here is what I am trying:

`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?parent=97`

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#arguments), the default number if results returned "per page" is 10. So you need to set `per_page` to however many you want to retrieve:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=30
```

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that out.